# Merge/combine contents of table cells with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the contents of all the cells in a row, combine them, and put them into a textarea. I think I need the .each() function, like:

```
 $('table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').text().appendTo(textarea); // not right
});
```

But I don't know how to combine the contents of each cell into one and then put it into the textarea.

Basically, I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I want it to end up like this:

```
<textarea>
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qy1e7to6/33/

I really appreciate any help you can give. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close! For each iteration of the `table row`, you want to combine the sequence of characters for each cell with a `,` separator. At the end, you want a `line break`.

One way we can easily combine the text with a `,` separator is using an array and then joining the array

```
var chars = []; 
// add characters here...
chars.join(',');
```

When we append, we can add the new line for the text:

```
var chars = [];

// iterate each cell and push to array to join later!
$(this).find('td').each(function(){
    chars.push($(this).text());
});

// append to text area and join the array
textarea.append(chars.join(','), '\n');
```

Here's an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qy1e7to6/34/

Comment: This worked perfectly. The other answer also works, but this one does not have the commas at the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this code works :

```
var msg = "";
$('table tr').each(function() {
 $(this).find('td').each(function(){
     msg += $(this).text() + ",";
 });
msg +=" \r\n";
});

$("textarea").val(msg);
```

fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/fr5htjyz/1/

Comment: THANK YOU. That worked great, but it has a comma at the end of each line. Can this be fixed?

Comment: please select as answer

Comment: 1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,
But Op wants 

1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
var content = '';    
$('table tr').each(function(idx,elem) {
   $(elem).find('tr').each(function(index,element){
     content += $(element).text() + ',';
});
content.splice(0,-1);
content + = '\n';
});
$(textarea).val(content);
```